# keep li's vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

Got a problem, where if an "a" inside of "li" has 2 lines of text, that "li" sits higher than "li" with one line.

html is a standard div>ul>li
here is the css

```
ul#menu-main-menu {
/*this is to make li's go beyond the container width*/
    position:absolute;
    left:16%;
    right:-100%;
    }
ul#menu-main-menu li {  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 148px;
    }        
ul#menu-main-menu li a {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    }
```

jsfiddle added
https://jsfiddle.net/dLmwp5kp/

Comment: Can you post whole code / a demo?

Comment: `vertical-align: top \ middle \ bottom` is what you need - [here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/bqeqzngf/). You simply need to change the default vertical align which is `baseline` by default and moves with the baseline of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the property is set to display:inline-block the element which has biggest height is aligned to the middle of other element

more detailed explanation can be found here

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting

add `vertical-align: middle;` for `ul#menu-main-menu li` it will align them vertically

demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dLmwp5kp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dLmwp5kp/1/)**

CSS:

```
ul#menu-main-menu li {  
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
     float:left;
    }        
ul#menu-main-menu li a {
     height: 35px;
    line-height:16px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul#menu-main-menu {
/*this is to make li's go beyond the container width*/
    position:absolute;
    left:16%;
    right:-100%;
  list-style:none;
    }
ul#menu-main-menu li {  
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    }        
ul#menu-main-menu li a {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <ul id="menu-main-menu">
       <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
       <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
       <li><a>Test 2lines</a></li>
       <li><a>Test 2lines</a></li>
       <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please check snippet for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just  put up  display:inline-block and  vertical-align:top;  in  both "li" and "a".

```
ul#menu-main-menu li {  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;

    }        
ul#menu-main-menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 5px;        
    padding: 0 2px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
}
```